# WooCommerce META Fields in Category Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

My client wants a strapline under each product name where products are shown on the category page.

I understand that the best option is to include the strapline as a Custom Field and then show that information using:

```
<?php the_meta(); ?>
```

This seems to work perfectly well on the Product Page when used within the file `woocommerce/single-product/meta.php`, however it doesn't show up when I add it to any of the other files within the woocommerce folder (and I think by now I have added it to almost everything in various places to test it).

Can anyone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is actually fairly straightforward once you know the right place to post the php.

Find the file woocommerce/content-product.php

Look for this line:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

and paste this beneath it:

```
<?php the_meta(); ?>
```

...and you should be good to go.